# Notepad plus plus shortcut for reloading files

Tags: notepad++

Is there any keyboard shortcut for reloading files in n++ ?
How can i configure my own?

Steps to reproduce:

- right click and reload on header tab.

Answer (score 73, accepted):

Steps for mapping a keyboard shortcut for reloading files in n++.

1. First open Notepad++ application
2. Now go to Settings tab >Shortcut mapper
3. Now here select the first tab which is **main menu**
4. You can find the "*reload from disk*" option under the selected options. *Note: Typically this is amongst the top commands, e.g. item #6*.
5. Now all you have to do is to assign an unused shortcut key mapping to it.

*Note: If you want to use `F5` like in a web-browser, it is better to first remove existing F5 shortcut assigned to "Run..." (close to bottom of **main menu**)*

Comment: From what i can see its mapped to ctrl + R by default in later versions of notepad++

Answer (score 4):

This page gives an explanation on how to set custom shortcuts in Notepad++:

http://www.martinrinehart.com/frontend-engineering/engineers/tools/notepad-pp/shortcuts.html

Summary: Go to the Settings=>Shortcut mapper menu item & set "Reload from Disk" there.

Answer (score 0):

Notepad++ in latest versions (I've checked on 7.8.8, but this was probably introduced earlier) can reload current file by clicking <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F5</kbd>